# How to get operands of 'lea' instruction using PIN?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address, instructions, intel-pin

I'm developing a taint analysis tool using PIN.

And I have a question, How to get operands of `lea` instruction?

About lea instruction like `lea rdx, ptr [rip+0x2244aa]`,
getting the first operand using `INS_OperandReg(ins, 0)` is possible.

But I want to check if the second operand is tainted, but I cannot get it.
And I couldn't find any function that returns the value of `rip+0x2244aa`

Is there any function that I can get the memory address(second operand) in lea?

Comment: I haven't tested (so I can't guarantee it's correct) but my best guess would be to use `INS_IsLea()` to check if it's a `LEA`, then test for a RIP relative using a combination of `INS_OperandMemoryBaseReg()` (and test for `REG_INST_PTR` which would indicate a RIP relative addressing) and `INS_OperandMemoryDisplacement`to get the Disp32; once you have that, get the RIP of the current instruction (+ its size) and just add them to the displacement to get the "real" value that would be loaded into the destination register.

Answer (score 1):

To access the operands used in a typical lea instruction, which has the form:

```
EffectiveAddress =  base + (index * scale) + displacement
```

So you have to access each individual values,

```
if(INS_OperandMemoryIndexReg(ins,1) != REG_INVALID_) 
  { /* get index register */
   INT64 scale = INS_OperandMemoryScale (ins, I);//value of scale: 1, 2, 4, 8.
  }
if(INS_OperandMemoryBaseReg(ins, 1) != REG_INVALID_) 
  { /* get base register */}
if(INS_OperandMemoryDisplacement (ins, 1) != 0)
  { /* get displacement value */}
```

Finally, you will know what registers are used or even calculate the actual values of the given effective memory address by calculating them up, (if you got their values by PIN_GetContextRegval(...) ).

Comment: The segment_base is not part of the "effective address"; LEA just does the offset part of the calculation.  (Also the segment register *value* isn't the same as the base.  But anyway that doesn't matter because LEA doesn't touch segmentation at all, in any mode.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I modified it. Thanks.

Comment: There's a corner case that will never come up in normal code because it's inefficient and pointless, but is possible if someone is trying to fool a PIN tool: `lea rax, [edi + edx]` or similar (REX.W and 32-bit address size overrides).  The effective-address calculation will be truncated to 32-bit even though the destination register is 64.  So if you want to know the operand values, you might also need to check the address-size if you want to correct address (even if PIN register numbers already distinguish 32 vs. 64-bit registers.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Can this case be generated in binary files by ordinary compilers to be fed further to the PIN tool for instrumentation, or generate by Intel Pin JIT?

Comment: No sane compiler will ever generate that, and hopefully even novice humans would at worst do `lea eax, [edi+edx]` (instead of the optimal `lea eax, [rdi+rdx]`).  If your PIN tool is trying to check / enforce something about code running under it, 32-bit address-size overrides might be a way for malicious code to fool it, but it's not something you normally have to worry about.  (For non-LEA instruction, `gcc -mx32` will often use 32-bit address size for loads / stores to make sure address math doesn't overflow the low 32 bits, e.g. with a negative int that's not zero-extended to 64-bit.)